# jquery .val() to change attribute selected state

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery to update a select option when a value is returned via an ajax call. I've put this back to its simplest form and whilst the visible value changes, the 'selected' attribute stays

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#fetchCAP").on('click',function (e) {
        $('#used_car_colour').val('grey');
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="button button-primary" name="fetchCAP" id="fetchCAP" value="Fetch">

<select name="used_car_colour" id="used_car_colour">
  <option class="colour-option" value="">None</option>
  <option class="colour-option" value="black" selected="">Black</option>
  <option class="colour-option" value="brown">Brown</option>
  <option class="colour-option" value="grey">Grey</option>
  <option class="colour-option" value="white">White</option>
</select>
```

Clicking the Fetch button will change the selected value to Grey. selected attribute should also change to Grey, but stays as Black.

Comment: it works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/h4sqc3zd/

Comment: Why do you have to change the selected attribute here ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to worry about the "selected" attribute - it simply defines which option is selected when the page loads.  When the selection changes (either via user selection or script), the "selected" attribute stays and is no longer useful.  When the form is posted or the selection is read via JavaScript, the actual selected value will be used.

You can always get the current selected value like this:

```
var selected = $('#used_car_colour').val();
```

Also, the "selected" attribute should be written without the ="", as follows:

```
<option class="colour-option" value="black" selected>Black</option>
```

If you absolutely must change which option has the "selected" attribute, then you would have to change it via JavaScript when the selection changes.  But I've never seen a situation where this is necessary and I suspect you really don't need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the selected option via the [attribute-selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and set the `selected`-attribute:

```
$("#fetchCAP").on('click', function (e) {
    $('#used_car_colour option').attr('selected', false); 
    //remove all other selected-attributes

    $('#used_car_colour').val('grey');
    $('#used_car_colour option[value=grey]').attr('selected', true); 
    //set the selected attribute to the selected option
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o2Lpxhzd/)

Comment: My understanding was .val() should do that for you?

Comment: @JonathanGarrett No, and the getter of the `val()`-function does not depending on the `selected`-attribute. It only depends on the input of the user, so which is selected at the moment the function triggers.

Comment: @JonathanGarrett In generall there is no need to set the `selected`-attribute unless there is some e.g. css depending on it.

Comment: you made a good point about not needing the selected state other than on page load. This made me look back at how I was saving this value and more importantly selecting the value on page load. It turned out I had checked the value against something wrong and would always return 'Black'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way-

```
$("#fetchCAP").on('click',function (e) {  
       $('#used_car_colour').find('option[value="grey"]').attr('selected','selected');
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/08dxqsxu/

Also for removing another option's selected attribute this would be-

```
$('#used_car_colour').find('option[value="grey"]').attr('selected','selected').siblings().removeAttr('selected');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sng620x1/